# Kibana time query, without date (with KQL)

Tags: elasticsearch, time, kibana, elasticsearch-dsl, kibana-7

I would like to find all documents within my index which have a timestamp between time 12:00:00 and 13:00:00 (24hr-format), regardless the date.

I can not find the KQL expression for this. Also the graphical filter method requires a specific date (wildcards does not work).

In the console I tried something like this:

```
# Does not work:
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "gt": "12:00:00",
        "lt": "13:00:00",
        "format": "HH:mm:ss"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Filter methods with date (e.g. "2020-11-16T12:00:00") work properly, so there is no issue with the timestamp. I am aware of the timezone of UTC, so at the end I have also to specify the timezone.

My ELK-stack has versions Kibana v7.10.0 and Elasticsearch v7.10.0.